# Apache FOP and java application

Tags: apache, apache-fop

What is APACHE FOP? is it a library for java to implement barcodes or what? can someone give me a general idea about it ,how does it works and where we work with,i have search for it in google but all the answers seems to me streng ,my teacher told me to read about it in order to use it to generate barcodes within a java application really i'm lost'

Answer (score 0):

Apache FOP is an [XSL-FO formatter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL-FO). It has nothing to do with barcodes per se. If all you need is a general purpose barcode generation library written in Java, take a look at [Barcode4J](http://barcode4j.sf.net).